# On Windows - where is a mqji.properties for me to use?

Tags: java, message-queue, ibm-mq

My application is a stand alone Java app, that customers download, install and run. It uses MQ to communicate with a host, which has been working for years. Neither myself nor customers have anything MQ installed on their Windows machines; we include and use com.ibm.mq.jar to do the work.

Apparently though, MQ needs a mqji.properties file in the classpath to prevent this :

```
Unable to load message catalog - mqji
com.ibm.mq.MQException: Message catalog not found
```

So my question is : Where do I get one??

Comment: If it has been running for years, what happened to the old one?  What have you changed that made it stop working all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a copy of my mqji.properties file.

Copy and paste into a text editor.
Save as mqji.properties
Put the directory that this file is in into your CLASSPATH.

```
# mqjiEn_US.properties
# Messages produced by the Websphere MQ Java interface classes
# (shared by bindings and by client)
# Messages beginning with MQJI are explanations for exceptions
# Messages beginning with MQJE are errors
#
# From class MQDistributionList
#
1=MQJI001: Queue manager object was null.
2=MQJI002: Not connected to a queue manager.
3=MQJI003: No object records supplied.
4=MQJI004: No response records supplied.
5=MQJI005: Not enough response records supplied.
6=MQJI006: An object or response record was null.
7=MQJI007: openResponse parameter was null.
8=MQJI008: Null message passed to put.
9=MQJI009: Null put message options passed to put.
10=MQJI010: Number of message trackers and response records do not match.
11=MQJI011: The distribution list has been closed.
#
# From class MQEnvironment
#
12=Websphere MQ Client for Java v5.3
#
# From class MQGetMessageOptions
#
13=MQJI013: Unsupported version number - {0}
14=MQJI014: Insufficient data received from queue manager.
15=MQJI015: Erroneous eyecatcher : {0}
#
# From class MQManagedObject
#
16=MQJI016: Object has been closed.
17=MQJI017: No selectors specified.
#
# From class MQMD
#
18=MQJI015: Erroneous eyecatcher : {0}
19=MQJI018: Array copy error in MQMD
#
# From class MQMessage
#
20=MQJI019: Malformed UTF string in MQMessage::readLine
21=MQJI020: Unsupported codeset : {0}
22=MQJI021: String index error occurred during codeset conversion
23=MQJI015: Erroneous eyecatcher : {0}
#
# From class MQOD
#
24=MQJI022: Unmatched number of object and response records
#
# From class MQPutMessageOptions
#
25=MQJI023: Null MQMessageTracker object supplied
#
# From class MQMessageTracker
#
26=MQJI024: Array copy error in MQMessageTracker
#
# From class MQQueue
#
27=MQJI025: Null MQMessage passed to get
28=MQJI026: Null MQGetMessageOptions passed to get
29=MQJI027: The queue has been closed
30=MQJI028: Null MQMessage passed to put
31=MQJI029: Null MQPutMessageOptions passed to put
#
# From class MQQueueManager
#
32=MQJI030: The queue manager does not support distribution lists.
#
# From class MQS390FloatSupport
#
33=MQJI031: Number outside of range for double precision S/390 Float
#
# From class MQS390PackedDecimalSupport
#
34=MQJI032: Invalid sign nibble in packed decimal
35=MQJI033: Packed Decimal digit outside of range 0-9
36=MQJI034: Outside of range for short packed decimal (+/-999)
37=MQJI035: Outside of range for integer packed decimal (+/-9999999)
38=MQJI036: Outside of range for long packed decimal (0+/-999999999999999)
#
# From class MQException
#
39=MQJE001: Completion Code {0}, Reason {1}
40=MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code {0}, Reason {1}\n{2}
#
# Messages produced by client only classes...
#
41=MQJI037: Error occurred during Websphere MQ API call - reason code {0}
42=MQJI038: Unexpected internal error during string index processing
43=MQJE002: Socket output stream was null
44=MQJE003: IO error transmitting message buffer
45=MQJE004: Socket input stream was null
46=MQJE005: TSH eyecatcher not found.  Eyecatcher was {0}
47=MQJE006: Internal error during array copy
48=MQJE007: IO error reading message data
49=MQJE008: IOException whilst sending status message
50=MQJE009: Failed to build API header
51=MQJE010: Unknown host: {0}
52=MQJE011: Socket connection attempt refused
53=MQJE012: Security error - cannot connect to host {0}
54=MQJE013: Error accessing socket streams
55=MQJE014: Control Point rejected connection
56=MQJE015: Error connecting to Control Point
57=MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect\n\Closure reason = {0}
58=MQJE017: MQ queue manager sent status error {0} during connect
59=MQJE018: Protocol error - unexpected segment type received
60=MQJE019: Error creating initial data segment
61=MQJE020: CCSID not supported by queue manager
62=MQJE021: Encoding not supported by queue manager
63=MQJE022: FAP level not supported by queue manager
64=MQJE023: Negotiation failed on maximum messages per batch
65=MQJE024: Sequence wrap value not supported by queue manager
66=MQJE025: Channel closed after two initial changes.  Closure reason {0}
67=MQJE026: Queue manager sent status error {0} during connect
68=MQJE027: Queue manager security exit rejected connection with error code {0}
69=MQJE028: Channel closed during security exchanges
70=MQJE029: Unexpected message type sent by queue manager
71=MQJE030: IOException during security flows
72=MQJE031: Security exit closed the channel
73=MQJE032: Queue manager security exit rejected connection with reason code {0}
74=MQJE033: A required security flow was not sent by the queue manager
75=MQJE034: Unexpected message type sent by queue manager
76=MQJE035: Negotiated maximum transmission size is too small
77=MQJE036: Queue manager rejected connection attempt
78=MQJE037: Remote queue manager closed the connection
79=MQJE038: Unexpected segment type {0} received
80=MQJE039: IOException whilst building connection data stream
81=MQJE040: Channel closed by exit
82=MQJE041: Unsupported version number - (0)
83=MQJE042: Erroneous eyecatcher: {0}
84=MQJE043: Insuffucient data received from queue manager
85=MQJE044: Array copy error in MQMD
86=MQJE045: Malformed UTF string
87=MQJE046: Unsupported codeset : {0}
88=MQJE047: String index error occurred during codeset conversion
89=MQJE048: Invalid sign nibble in packed decimal
90=MQJE049: Packed Decimal digit outside of range 0-9
91=MQJE050: Outside of range for short packed decimal (+/-999)
92=MQJE051: Outside of range for integer packed decimal (+/-9999999)
93=MQJE052: Outside of range for long packed decimal (0+/-999999999999999)
94=Websphere MQ Bindings for Java v5.3
95=MQJE053: The Websphere MQ Bindings for Java library could not be loaded
96=MQJE054: The queue manager does not support distribution lists
97=MQJE055: The queue manager does not support version 2 Websphere MQ API structures
98=MQJE056: Initial negotiation failure
99=MQJE057: Channel closed during security exchanges
100=MQJE058: Invalid number of object or response records
101=MQJE059: String index error
102=MQJE060: Could not find class {0}
103=MQJE061: Could not find field {0}
104=MQJE062: Could not find method {0}
#
# Messages used by MQManagedConnectionJ11, ManagedConnectionFactories
# and MQManagedConnectionMetaData
#
105=MQJI039: Invalid ConnectionRequestInfo object
106=MQJI040: MQManagedConnection already destroyed
107=MQJI041: Method {0} is not supported by Websphere MQ Classes for Java
108=MQJI042: MQManagedConnection is not reusable
#
# Messages from MQManagedConnectionMetaData
#
109=IBM Websphere MQ
110=Command Level {0}
#
# Messages from MQXAi
#
111=Security manager prevented access to native methods library for MQ XA support.
112=Failed to load native methods library for MQ XA support.
#
# Messages from MQXAResource
#
113=xa_open failed
114=XA operation failed, see errorCode
115=XAResource closed

#
# Messages produced by com.ibm.mq.MQMsg2
#
116=MQJE063: Unsupported character set {0}
117=MQJE064: Unsupported version of MQMD structure {0}
118=MQJE065: Inconsistent internal state detected

# message when server doesn't support client XA
119=client connection not XA enabled

#
# Messages produced via SSL options on a client connection
#
120=MQJE066: {0} provided as an unsupported object type
121=MQJE067: Peer name {0} did not match requested name {1}
122=MQJE068: Server certificate has been revoked
123=MQJE069: Unable to contact CertStore
124=MQJE070: SSL Protocol error: Channel not configured for SSL?
```

Comment: There's a basic question here whether the purpose of SO is to help people get something working in any way possible, even if it is unreliable and brittle, or if the idea is to point them toward the answer that is reliable and production-ready.  Here is someone producing a paid, licensed product into which they are embedding bits and pieces of another vendor's code.  Not only is it brittle and unreliable (as evidenced by the question itself) but it is illegal and places both the poster's company and their customers at risk. -1 for an answer that perpetuates these issues.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer here is that the customers need to download the actual WMQ client and install it with your application and that your application should be distributed without the WMQ client jars.  This is true for a variety of reasons:

- You are not authorized to redistribute the vendor's code.  When WMQ client or server code is bundled in an OEM license, it is the full install and not just a few jar files.
- One of the reasons for installing the full client is to get support.  The full client install is free and includes a number of diagnostic facilities.  The only reason not to require a full install is convenience and if you are charging money for the app any convenience is far outweighed by potential liability.
- Maintenance.  If the customer installs the WMQ client then they can apply periodic maintenance from IBM and know that it is a complete and intact distribution.  Unless your company is prepared to guarantee that the components they choose to redistribute are a valid installation, you are better off using the official install.  Given the nature of the question is asking this community what the valid non-vendor installation is, I don't see how your company can stand behind this configuration of IBM's code.
- Regulatory compliance.  If any of your customers are subject to PCI, SOX, HIPAA or government regulations, certification cannot be achieved under this configuration.  For example, to be PCI compliant the deployed application must have applied Fix Pack 7.0.1.3 quite some time ago.  Without the full install, it is impossible to apply the fix pack or prove to an auditor it has been installed based on the jars.
- Security.  If you are not using SSL or an exit than it is possible for your customers to impersonate one another or the WMQ administrative account.  In order to be using SSL you would have to have installed the IBM JCCE provider which comes in GSKit, which is part of the full client install and contains native compiled C code ot available in jar files.  Based on the description of the app, I'm guessing any of your customers can remotely, anonymously administer your QMgr and execute arbitrary OS code.  Not good.

So the correct answer is for you and your clients to go download and install the full WMQ client ([SupportPac MQC7](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC7)) and configure the app to run on that.  Anything less places your clients and your company at risk.

And if you have any doubt about the security exposures I mentioned, please refer to the IMPACT *Hardening WebSphere MQ* presentation and the *WebSphere MQ Hands-on Security Lab* [posted here](http://t-rob.net/links).